# How to pass a php variable to javascript that is being executed by php

Tags: javascript, php

I have some javascript code that is executed by php. The reason for this is I tried to print to a printer but I couldn't get php code to do it.

But the javascript code can. And I need to post a variable to the javascript so it knows what to print. Therefore I know I can post to php and from there echo the javascript to connect and print to my label printer. The last hurdle is passing in the variable received by POST to the javascript.

```
$val = "variable";
echo '<script>
var val = "<?php echo $val; ?>";      \\ trying to put the variable into the javascript
var format_start = "^XA^LL200^FO80,50^A0N36,36^FD";
var format_end = "^FS^XZ";
BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice(\'printer\', function(printer) {
  default_printer = printer

...
```

Comment: never mix php and js like this. They're executed differently and can cause unexpected behaviour. Use AJAX. Also, you try opening PHP again inside an echo'd string - that will render as `<?php echo $val; ?>` - not the actual value of `$val`.

Comment: Ok I must admit I did start to think it was getting a bit crazy but this was just a really small section of my system. So will the javascript still be able to be executed without an actual individual using a browser?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comenters about not doing this, there is a simple misunderstanding in your code:

You are running PHP to output JS from the echo, you do not need to output the PHP tags, you can just output the variable, and when the page renders, the variable substitution will occur.

So, this:

```
var val = "<?php echo $val; ?>";
```

Should be

```
var val = "$val";
```

The JS at page render, visible via view source, will now look like:

```
var val = "myValVarContents";
```

I hope that helps, even though as said, this is generally a bad idea

D